# If $X, Y, Z$ are positive i.i.d. r.v.s, why is $E(\frac X{X+Y+Z})=E(\frac Y{X+Y+Z})=E(\frac Z{X+Y+Z})$?

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation

I understand that i.i.d. r.v.s are independent and have the same probability distribution, but I don't understand why that implies $$E\left(\frac X{X+Y+Z}\right)=E\left(\frac Y{X+Y+Z}\right)=E\left(\frac Z{X+Y+Z}\right)$$

The original problem was:

> Let $X, Y, Z$ are positive i.i.d. r.v.s, find $E\left(\dfrac X{X+Y+Z}\right)$

The solution contained the aforementioned result, and at the end concluded that $$E\left(\frac X{X+Y+Z}\right)=\frac13$$

A simple explanation, please! :)

Comment: By symmetry, if you do the permutation:
$$ X\to Y,\quad Y\to Z,\quad Z\to X $$
It will be the same since they have independently identical distributions.

Comment: Related:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2675669/x-1-x-2-x-3-sim-texti-i-d-r0-1-find-e-fracx-1x-2x-1x-2x-3.

Answer (score 1):

By symmetry, the random variables $U = \frac{X}{X+Y+Z}$, $V = \frac{Y}{X+Y+Z}$ and $W = \frac{Z}{X+Y+Z}$ have the same probability distribution since $(X,Y,Z)$, $(Y,Z,X)$ and $(Z,X,Y)$ are identically distributed. Hence $U,V,W$ have same expectation.

However some hypotheses are missing here, for instance $X,Y,Z$ with nonzero positive values. Otherwise it might happen that $U,V,W$ are not well-defined  (if a division by zero occurs) or don't have a finite expectation.

Comment: "By the way, independence is irrelevant here." By the way, independence is **very much relevant** here. As you would know if you had made the symmetry argument more precise that it is now.

Comment: Are you sure you understood why the distributions are the same? Reading your answer, the doubt creeps in...

Comment: This argument (modified to be more spot on) should be in your answer.

Comment: @Did: there was a time when I could be more lazy. But of course you are right!

Comment: Thanks :). Would you, please, complete your favor by providing a concrete example, so that I understand your answer fully?